# Alphavantage datatype conflict and endpoint URL error on deploying app to alexa

Tags: json, node.js, csv, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently working on an alexa app and recently started using the alphavantage API.

I am unable to incorporate the JSON datatype format into my javascript code, the resultant endpoint URL always has the datatyple as csv.

System info: Windows 10, 64bit, node version 6.9.1

I am able to retrieve the data on my system (**with the datatype as csv and not json**).
[image: Output on my while trying it on my system]

But on deploying the code on amazon I get a timeout error with endpoint URL pointing to datatype CSV. I am aware the timeout error might be because of delay in loading the data. But my concern is with the datatype format being csv and not json.
[image: Alexa Error Log]

Part of the nodejs code deployed on alexa :

```
'use strict';
var AlphaVantageAPI = require('alpha-vantage-cli').AlphaVantageAPI;
var yourApiKey = 'KJT2NTA5M7HW66RB';
var alphaVantageAPI = new AlphaVantageAPI(yourApiKey, 'compact', true);

alphaVantageAPI.getIntradayData('HDFC', '60min')
    .then(intradayData => {
        console.log("Intraday data:");
        console.log(intradayData[0].High);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

It would be great if you could help me out with details on how to override the CSV to JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

If you just delete the datatype AlphaVantage default returns JSON data.

Your request would look something like:

> https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

Hope this helps